# Django queryset evaluation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-1.11

Let say i have queryset like follow.

```
queryset1 = Staff.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id).values_list("department_id", flat=True)
```

if i am trying to pass queryset 1 to new queryset like below

```
queryset_form_1 = Department.objects.filter(pk__in=list(queryset1))
queryset_form_2 = Department.objects.filter(pk__in=queryset1)
```

as i mentioned above if i `eval` the queryset1 with `list(queryset1)` it fetch the expected result but if i try like in `queryset_form_2` it fetch all records what mistake i made?

Comment: I think both versions should work the same way. Can you provide the results of your queries?

Answer (score 0):

[Django QuerySet is lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

So you should use first one , because list(queryset1) force evaluate a lazy query. And you will get your expected result .